# Manipulating drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-drawable

I want to make some Drawable as a background of a TextView. The TextView length will be vary and I want the Drawable to expand with the TextView. I set the Drawable as the background of the TextView but it looks weird.

this is my TextView:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />
```

and this is my @drawable/background. It is just a round shape vector:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    >

    <path
        android:fillColor="#80000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2z"
        />

</vector>
```

[image]
[image]

I want the drawable to expand with the TextView length (it might have more than one line) but keep the shape of the edge (rounded). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create shape drawable as per below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/yourgraycolor" />

    <padding android:top="@dimen/margin_vsmall" android:bottom="@dimen/margin_vsmall" android:left="@dimen/margin_small" android:right="@dimen/margin_small" />

    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/radius" />

</shape>
```

And apply to your textview as background `android:background="@drawable/yourshapedrawable`

Here adjust your radius and padding as per your need.

Comment: it works. Can I change the shape of one of the edge or corner with some shape just like chat bubble callout?

Comment: @RonaldSumbayak : Use 9 patch image in case of chat bubble, because using shape drawable you couldn't properly get  bubble shape

Comment: no, not really a bubble shaped, just add something in the corner. Did I need to use 9 patch image to do that? (see my updated question)

Comment: i have upvoted it, but my rep still not 15 yet. haha

Comment: @RonaldSumbayak : yeah for that, 9 patch would be better option! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give some padding on TextView like this

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
/>
```

Comment: that will only enlarge the drawable and there will be too many space because of the padding. I want it to keep fit to the TextView while expanding with its length.

Comment: you can try it by adjusting padding according to your requirement